# How to skip value cannot be null?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a data grid that contains record from the database. I can save data into database without uploading image to its folder and the column for the image name in the database would be empty. When I tried to delete any row that have an empty image name column it display an error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path3')'.

I want to ignore this error so that l can delete record from the database that does not have a corresponding image in its folder.

```
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody] ICRUDModel<Employee> value)
{
    Employee order = _context.Employee.Where(c => c.EmployeeId == (int)value.key).FirstOrDefault();
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/Photos", order.Passport!);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
                   
    _context.Employee.Remove(order);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return Json(order);
}
```

| Id | EmployeeName | Position | ImageName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Annah | Admin Assistant | annah.png |
| 2 | Maria | Manager |  |

Expected output

| Id | EmployeeName | Position | ImageName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Annah | Admin Assistant | annah.png |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is due to the 3rd parameter of `Path.Combine()` being null, ie, `order.Passport!`.

You can skip the file deletion and still delete the Employee record by checking for the `order.Passport` for null like below.  You may want to consider handling the case where `Employee order` is null, too.

```
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody] ICRUDModel<Employee> value)
{
    Employee order = _context.Employee.Where(c => c.EmployeeId == (int)value.key).FirstOrDefault();
    
    if (order.Passport is not null) 
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
               "wwwroot/Photos", 
               order.Passport!);  // this will not be null here
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
                   
    _context.Employee.Remove(order);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return Json(order);
}
```